# Npgsql 3 Geometry x Invalid endian flag value encountered using writer.Write<NpgsqlLine>

Tags: npgsql

I have using previous version of npgsql (2.0.7), it works fine.
Now I have upgrade to npgsql 3.0.5 
and with new rewrite of copy method of 3.0.5
I have to change code for geometry

I try to using

```
while 
{
    var line = new NpgsqlLine(122149.006850, 483672.683450, 122156.366150);
    writer.Write<NpgsqlLine>(line, NpgsqlDbType.Line)
}
writer.Close();
```

at debug mode : in the loop is ok, but when writer.Close()
Error!! with this message

```
XX000: Invalid endian flag value encountered.
```

Need help on this, any suggestion are highly appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you as I was having the same problem.

In my case, it has been resolved by taking away my "using" directive :

instead of:

```
using (var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport("sql copy from stdin command"){  ///writer.StartRow(); writer.Write(...); writer.Write();}
```

Take away using :

```
var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport("sql copy from stdin command");
then in while statement:
while(condition){writer.StartRow(); writer.Write(...); writer.Write();}
```

I think the problem comes from `writer.Dispose()` managed by using directive : In fact, without using directive, if you call your `writer.Dispose()`, the same Npgsql exception is raised.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Above does not work - in 4.05 you have to do

```
dbimporter.Complete()
```

but this works for all geometry types loading into a geometry column in postgres

using

```
Dim conn As New NpgsqlConnection

Dim ct As String = "COPY " + datatab + "( " + datacolumns + ") FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"

Dim dbimporter = conn.BeginBinaryImport(ct)
```

when you need to import geometry data use this, you will need `sqlserverdatatypes` dll

```
dim wkt1 as string ="POINT(7 7)" - any wkt geometry representation

Dim udtText1 As New System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(wkt1)
Dim sqlGeometry11 As Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry = Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STGeomFromText(udtText1, srid)

Dim ms1 As New MemoryStream()
Dim bw1 As New BinaryWriter(ms1)
Dim WKB1() As Byte = sqlGeometry11.STAsBinary().Buffer
bw1.Write(WKB1)

dbimporter.Write(WKB1, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea)
```